# rails db:seed will not populate a negative value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

this has to have an obvious answer that I'm missing!

schema.rb has

```
create_table "table_name", :force => true do |t|
     t.integer my_columnname, :limit =>8
```

seeds.rb has

```
TableName.create([{"my_columnname"=>-1}])
```

But when looking at the database the value is 0 e.g. zero. it does not populate properly.

notes:

- if I change -1 to say 999, the database value IS 999. so I know seeds.rb format is ok
- i have attempted using :my_columname instead of "my_columnname", no difference
- I've search for any examples of problems with seeding negative values, no-one seems to have same problem
- I did have this working in the past so I've diff'd seeds,schemas and migration files and application.rb. The ONLY difference seems to be the :limit => 8 (I need big int). But everything I've researched says that BIGINTs are signed. so that "should not" be the issue.
- I have logged into mysql to look at table type -  it is bigint
- I have removed the :limit from my current version and it still does not populate
- i have logged into mysql command line and performed an sql insert with a negative value and it populates.
- rake db:seed --trace does not show any errors.

** UPDATES **

- attempting to insert a value 9999999999999999999 results in error: Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column 'qty_included_standard'

  - I have tried setting value to "-1" or -1. no difference still will not set to -1
- using the console, the actual value being submitted to the DB is zero not -1 (see value_included_standard below). But if i make -1 888, it submits 888.

  014-02-17 20:55:02", special_consideration: nil>] 
      1.9.3-head :009 > TransactionType.create([{"transaction_type"=>"20", "value_included_standard"=>-1, "qty_included_standard"=>"8", "cost_per_transaction_standard"=>"1000", "standard_included_in_overall"=>"false", "special_consideration"=>nil, :plan_id=>1}])
         (0.3ms)  BEGIN
        SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `transaction_types` (`cost_per_transaction_standard`, `cost_per_transaction_within`, `created_at`, `flag_fall_cost_for_transaction`, `min_block_for_transaction`, `plan_id`, `qty_included_standard`, `qty_included_within`, `special_consideration`, `standard_included_in_overall`, `transaction_type`, `updated_at`, `value_included_standard`, `value_included_within`, `withintype_included_in_overall`) VALUES (1000, 0, '2014-02-17 20:55:43', 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, NULL, 0, '20', '2014-02-17 20:55:43', 0, 0, NULL)

what am I doing wrong. is there something in migrations/schema that is restricting signed values?

hope this is obvious to someone.

```
            ** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
    WE HAVE INITIALISED
    ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
    ** Execute db:seed
```

Comment: As far as I know, `create` takes a hash, not a list containing a hash.   Make it `TableName.create( {:my_columnname => -1} )`.  Also for this to work, `my_columname` must be bulk assignment enabled with `attr_accessible`. The fact that the command is in a seed file doesn't signify anything. What happens when you do this from the rails console?  Run the command and then `TableName.all` to see what happened.

Comment: Sorry I looked up `create` and the array should not be causing a problem, although it doesn't do anything either and can be removed.  In fact the curly braces are optional, too.

Comment: What version of Rails and Ruby are you using? I tried this with Rails 4.0 on Ruby 2.1 and the negative number gets seeded just fine. Only difference is that I used sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Will try console later. 
It is rails 3.0
Attr is interesting. But as I mentioned it DOES work if I make the value say 888. That updates!

Comment: What happens if you use a number greater than 9223372036854775807 (the largest signed BigInt in MySQL)?  Try with 9999999999999999999 -- if that works, then you've got an unsigned int.

Comment: Zwippie I meant to say the annoying thing is this used to work. I've started to look at all the changes to the db since it did and figure out what has changed. We did not have a test case for this and so it has allowed to continue for many months across lots of changes

Comment: The console is telling: the INSERT INTO displayed after submitting the command does not pass in the parameter provided in the command line: e.g. I put "value_included_standard"=>-1,  as part of the Tablename.create but the debug output shows INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... 0 . e.g. zero is passed into the command. (full command in question above). Why on earth would the -1 not be passed into the actual command?

Comment: Do you have any funny validations or before_* filters on that model?  Could the model be restricting negative numbers on that field?

Comment: mr rogers - that is precisely what it was. i was so fixated on the db/schema changes i forgot the model!

Answer (score 0):

am I a complete idiot. sorry to all. there is a validator that was introduced that I forgot to check (we have outsourced development). I've been so fixated to schemas/migration definitions i forgot to check the "save" function! if you take out  self.send(f.to_s + '=', 0) if self.send(f) < 0  it works!!!!